# Cordova error in my upload audio

Tags: javascript, file, cordova, ionic-framework, file-transfer

I am developing an app with an audio upload this code worked before
i update cordova 5 to 6. I am not really sure the issue is cause the update.
The error in my logs is 
"error in coipy
console-via-logger.js (174,23)"

```
    var url = "domainname/app/upload.php";
    var targetPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory;

    var name1 = $scope.sound.name;
    var extension = $scope.sound.file.split(".").pop();
    var filepart = Date.now();
    var filename = filepart + "." + extension;
    console.log("new filename is " + filename);

    var options = {
        fileKey: "file",
        fileName: filename,
        chunkedMode: false,
        params: { 'directory': 'upload', 'fileName': filename, 'name': name1 }
    };

    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(targetPath, function (d) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL($scope.sound.file, function(fe) {
            fe.copyTo(d, filename, function(e) {
                console.log('success inc opy');
                $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: 'Save OK',
                    template: 'Save OK'
                });

                console.dir(e);
                $scope.sound.file = e.nativeURL;
                $scope.sound.path = e.fullPath;
                console.log($scope.sound.file);
                console.log($scope.sound.path);
                $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(url, $scope.sound.file , options).then(function (result) {
                    console.log("SUCCESS: " + JSON.stringify(result.response));
                }, function (err) {
                    console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(err));
                }, function (progress) {
                    // PROGRESS HANDLING GOES HERE
                });
                Sounds.save($scope.sound).then(function() {
                    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                        disableBack: true
                    });

                });

            }, function(e) {
                console.log('error in coipy');console.dir(e);
            });                 
        }, function(e) {
            console.log("error in inner bullcrap");
            console.dir(e);
        });
```

[image: error logs]

Comment: Are you using the latest file transfer plugin?

Comment: yes i am using it :/

Comment: @kratisphere also you gotta use latest  version of file plugin - 4.2.0 as this could be permission issue with Android marshmallow

Comment: also you gotta use latest  version of file plugin - 4.2.0 as this could be permission issue with Android marshmallow

Comment: @Gandhi 4.1.1 for file and 1.5.1 for file transfer

Comment: use file plugin 4.2.0 as older version won't work with android 6 due to permission issue. Also ensure to use latest version of file transfer. I m sure this should do especially file plugin latest

Comment: same issue with 4.2.0 plugin file

Comment: could you inspect the error object e in the function which logs the message error in copy and post the same  to narrow down the issue

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/imTgz

Comment: sorry, currently I m accessing SO in my mobile and not able to see your screenshot properly. All I wanted was error code and message

Comment: oh sure sorry. error in coipy - console-via-logger.js(174,23)

Comment: I m asking you for the error code and error message not the message which you log in the console

Comment: i have not error message just 
nothing is happening when i push button "save" except this message in the logs javascript.

Comment: if it logged the error message 'error in coipy', it means that it has got into error callback function. All I need is to inspect the object e and post e.error code and e.message

Comment: i need to add something in my javascript code to do that? sorry i don't know what i need to do

Comment: You just needed to inspect the error object in debug mode and let us know the values

Comment: name: FileError
ENCODING_ERR: 5
ABORT_ERR: 3
is this what you need?

Comment: sorry i could not answer to you yesterday

Comment: File encoding error means you gotta set proper content type and mime type in option before trying out upload

Comment: so what i need to change in my code?

Comment: set content type in options object. Look for the sample in official Cordova file transfer plugin github page

Comment: i added 'mimeType: "audio/amr",' in my options file but same issue

Comment: It should be set as options.mimeType = "audio/amr";

Comment: same if it is added in?
 var options = {
        fileKey: "file",
        fileName: filename,
        chunkedMode: false,
        params: { 'directory': 'upload', 'fileName': filename, 'name': name1 }
    };

Comment: this is FileError code 1 on the copyto

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114629/discussion-between-gandhi-and-kratosphere).